# Difference between "Bookmark History" permission tag

Tags: android, user-permissions

What is the difference between the two Android permission below related to browser Bookmark History?

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/> -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
```

My app works fine with the first one only, and crash with the second.

**SDK version:**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

**Error Log when I use the second permission tag:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.browser.provider.BrowserProvider2 uri content://browser/bookmarks from pid=5063, uid=10050 requires com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS, or grantUriPermission()
                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
                  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
                  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
                  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:385)
                  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:414)
                  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:357)
                  at course.labs.permissionslab.BookmarksActivity.loadBookmarks(BookmarksActivity.java:56)
                  at course.labs.permissionslab.BookmarksActivity.access$000(BookmarksActivity.java:14)
                  at course.labs.permissionslab.BookmarksActivity$1.onClick(BookmarksActivity.java:32)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Android version:** 4.3.1

Thanks!

Comment: show me the error log

Comment: Are you running the app on Android 6.0 Marshmallow ?

Answer (score 0):

This release removes support for global bookmarks. The `android.provider.Browser.getAllBookmarks()` and `android.provider.Browser.saveBookmark()` methods are now removed. Likewise, the READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS and WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS permissions are removed. If your app targets Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher, don't access bookmarks from the global provider or use the bookmark permissions. Instead, your app should store bookmarks data internally.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser